# why I cant deserlize json using datacontractserializer when using wrapped format

Tags: json, wcf

My wcf service uses the wrapped format body style. When I try deserializing it using DataContractJsonSerializer isn't deserializing the json properly

```
  SignInResult returnedUser = new SignInResult();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(provider.SignIn(username, password)));
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SignInResult),"root");
            returnedUser =  serializer.ReadObject(stream) as SignInResult;
            stream.Close();
            return returnedUser;
```

but I don't get a object populated according to the following json

```
{
  "SignInResult": {
    "CreationDate": "/Date(1480598102923+0000)/",
    "Email": "bladsa@as.com",
    "IsApproved": true,
    "IsLockedOut": false,
    "IsOnline": true,
    "IsValidLogin": true,
    "LastActivityDate": "/Date(1490954750307+0100)/",
    "LastLockoutDate": "/Date(-6816268800000+0000)/",
    "LastLoginDate": "/Date(1490954750307+0100)/",
    "LastPasswordChangedDate": "/Date(-2208988800000+0000)/",
    "ProviderName": "LoginProvider",
    "ProviderUserKey": "dcc5f38f-f71e-4d9d-bdb2-58fb60b7a65e",
    "UserName": "schoi"
  }
}
```

It does work if I use the bare format so it definately something to do with the wrapped message format.

I know I can do this in Newsoft json but I know I will get asked to use Microsofts way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its so simple. at first we create a `jsondeserilzer` method like this:

```
public static T DataJsonDeserializer<T>(string jsonString)
{
    var mStrm = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
    var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    var objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(mStrm);
    return (T)objResponse;
}
```

then we create a json object like this:

```
public class SignInResult
{
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
    public bool IsOnline { get; set; }
    public bool IsValidLogin { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLockoutDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    public string ProviderUserKey { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public SignInResult SignInResult { get; set; }
}
```

finally you can deserilze any thing like this:

```
    var x = JsonDeserializer<RootObject>(provider.SignIn(username, password)));
```

Comment: I assummed it need a wrapper like rootobject and I knew root obect was thing. I got an error message saying expecting SignInresult but got root object. I was too frustrated to connect the two together DOH!!